# How Is the time complexity of size function of stack constant if stack is implemented by linked list?

Tags: c++

At Any point of time if we invoke size function it means to calculate size we need to traverse whole linked list which is O(n).
I want to know about the standard template library c++ size function..
The only way to get O(1) is to keep a track of push and pop operations ? is it how it is done in c++ standard library?

Comment: *The only way to get O(1) is to keep a track of push and pop operations ?* And that's how it works.  FWIW, `std::stack` use `std::deque` as the underlying container by default.

Comment: A standard library implementation can do this any way it wants. The only way I know of is to have a `size` member that tracks insertions and removals. But if someone comes up with something else they are free to use it. The language is usually only requires behaviors, not how that behavior is achieved.

Comment: About which `size` function do you ask exactly? [`std::list::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size)? About which implementation of C++ standard library are you asking? [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/)? [llvm C++ library](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/)?

Comment: @KamilCuk About stack size function

Comment: Which one exactly is "stack size function"? Can you show some code? Och you mean [`std::stack::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/size)?

Comment: @Naman *At Any point of time if we invoke size function it means to calculate size we need to traverse whole linked list which is O(n)* -- Since C++ 11, the `std::list::size()` is constant, not `O(n)`.

Comment: There are several open-source implementations that you can just read. It's not easy reading, admittedly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How is it constant?

Comment: @Naman it's not that hard to have a `size_t size` data member to keep track of the size.

Comment: @Naman -- by having a member variable that keeps track of the size.  There are few, if any containers that when asked their size, they have to go through the gauntlet of traversing itself to find out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How is Stack implemented btw in stl ? by arrays or by linked lists?

Comment: @Naman A stack is a container adapter, it is not a container.  Please read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).  See that the second template argument is a `std::deque`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie By deafult it is implemented by deque? does container adapter means we can use any container to implement it?

Comment: The documentation says what the container must have `back`, `push_back`, `pop_back`.  So as long as your container supports those functions, it can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to traverse a list to know its size. As long as you keep the size as a member variable of the class and correctly increment/decrement it when the size of the list changes, returning the `size()` is a O(1) operation. The `size()` member function can be implemented as simply `size_t size() const noexcept { return m_size; }` or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..That means size function keeps track of operations and at any instant we can get the direct value of that variable

Comment: That is one possible implementation. But it is not the only one.

Comment: @KamilCuk nowhere do I say that other implementations are not possible. OP wanted to know how `size()` could be O(1) - I answered that by explaining one way it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

According to the container requirements (C++ 17, 26.2.1 General container requirements) if a container has member function size then its complexity is constant. And the standard container `std::list` has the member function size.

And the member function of the standard container adapter `std::stack` is defined like

```
size_type size() const { return c.size(); }
```

where `c` is the underlined container as for example `std::list`. So it also has the constant complexity.